# PHP comma separated string array Export to csv

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

im writing a script to download a csv,

the form i using to send data server like below,

(the value of hidden field has domain name,namerserver1,namerserver2,namerserver3,namerserver4) some have domain name and not have ns data

```
<form class="dmns2" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="wiseowldating.co.uk,ns.nothard.net,ns2.nothard.net,ns3.nothard.net" name="nsv[]" />
<input type="hidden" value="willow.nothard.net.zz" name="nsv[]" />
<input type="hidden" value="welditz.com,ns.nothard.net,ns2.nothard.net,ns3.nothard.net," name="nsv[]" />
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmit"  value="CSV Export"/>
</form>
```

I'm getting those values on php like below

```
if(isset($_POST['nsv'])){
foreach($_POST['nsv'] as $val){
    echo $val.'<br/>';
    }
exit(0);
}
```

the records are showing correctly as below

```
wiseowldating.co.uk,ns.nothard.net,ns2.nothard.net,ns3.nothard.net,
willow.nothard.net.zz,
welditz.com,ns.nothard.net,ns2.nothard.net,ns3.nothard.net,
```

but i want export this output to a csv files as this format

```
Doman                 nameserver1    nameserver2     nameserver3     nameserver4 nameserver5
wiseowldating.co.uk   ns.nothard.net ns2.nothard.net ns3.nothard.net
willow.nothard.net.zz
welditz.com           ns.nothard.net ns2.nothard.net ns3.nothard.net
```

this code is working, thanks for help

```
$fp = fopen("nsdata.csv", "w");
$row=array('Domain','NS1','NS2','NS3','NS4');
fputcsv($fp, $row);
foreach($_POST['nsv'] as $val){
    $ar=explode(',',$val);
    fputcsv($fp,$ar);
}
fclose($fp);
```

can anyone help me to do this using php please, i appreciate your help. thank you

Comment: [Explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on `,` to convert to an array, then use PHP's [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function with a "\t" separator

Comment: thanks do you have any example for sample codes

Comment: There's examples of using fputcsv() in the PHP documentation

Comment: i used below codes,but the created csv file not have datas
$fp = fopen("nsdata.csv", "w");
$row=array('Domain','NS1','NS2','NS3','NS4');
fputcsv($fp, $row);
foreach($_POST['nsv'] as $val){
 fputcsv($fp, $val, chr(9));
}

Comment: also tried by exploading, it only shows headers

Comment: `$ar=explode(',', $val);` __not__ `$ar=explode($val,',');`... the order of arguments is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of arguments to the explode() function is wrong

And `'\t'` is not the same as `"\t"`

And you're missing the `"\t"` when you write your headers as well

```
$fp = fopen("nsdata.csv", "w");
$row = array('Domain','NS1','NS2','NS3','NS4');
fputcsv($fp, $row, "\t");
foreach($_POST['nsv'] as $val){
    $ar=explode(',', $val);
    fputcsv($fp, $ar, "\t");
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: thanks i found it, no need \t, when i put that it not separating columns :)

Answer (score 1):

you  should try tabulator as separator

```
fputcsv($fp, $foo, chr(9));
```

Comment: i used below codes,but the created csv file not have datas
$fp = fopen("nsdata.csv", "w");
$row=array('Domain','NS1','NS2','NS3','NS4');
fputcsv($fp, $row);
foreach($_POST['nsv'] as $val){
 fputcsv($fp, $val, chr(9));
}

Comment: also tried using explode, it shows only headers
$fp = fopen("nsdata.csv", "w");
$row=array('Domain','NS1','NS2','NS3','NS4');
fputcsv($fp, $row);
foreach($_POST['nsv'] as $val){
 $ar=explode($val,',');
 fputcsv($fp,$ar,'\t');
}
fclose($fp);

Comment: @IreshaKumari Please don't post code as comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question instead. Also, any clarification should be done within / below the question, not below one of the answers.